# Specify local price for countries in Google Publish

Tags: localization, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, price

I have an Android app with a subscription offer and in app purchase offer.

I set up the local prices for the subscription offer, I was able to set up a specific local price for all my available countries.

Unfortunately for my in-app purchase offer, I'm not able to set up specific local prices for several countries (Burkina Faso, Mali, Ivory Coast...). I need to use the default price (and I don't want because the price needs to be adjusted for these countries.

I don't understand why it's possible for subscription and not for in app for these countries.

Did I miss something?

Thanks